# python3.3 tkinter ttk 'padding'

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.3

The padding option for widgets can be set like this:

```
frm = ttk.Frame(padding = "5 5 10 10")
```

I'd like to examine and change this during program execution, and have written this:

```
if frm['padding'] == "5 5 10 10":
    do something
```

The problem is, "5 5 10 10" is not returned!  I get pixel object at 0x1d753f0, etc.  As the memory location changes with every time the program runs, this is of no use to me.  How can I get a usable response?

Answer (score 0):

`frm['padding']` returns a tuple of pixel objects. You can get each pixel object value via its `string` attribute:

```
for po in f['padding']: 
    print po.string
```